# My background-image won't fit around my video elements

Tags: html, css

I can't for the life of me get my video to fit in the background image. I am not sure if I should just add the background in html. I think I just have to change background-position and size and I have tried but I still can't get it to fit. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<div class="videos">
    <div id="video1">
        <iframe width="450" height="315"src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vr0dXfQQfNU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="video2">
        <iframe width="450" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fevkx229XBs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>



div#video1 {
    float: right;
    background-image: url(images/vidborder.png);
    background-size: 110%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -50px center;
    width: 500px;
    height: 450px;
}

div#video2 {
    background-image: url(images/vidborder2.png);
    background-size: 10%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 500px;
    height: 450px;
}

.videos {
    margin-top: 40px;
}

iframe {
    margin-top: 35px;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean _it doesn't fit background image_?

Comment: the background image won't fit around my video. It's either too small or I can't get it centered.

Comment: @hinockurt How do you expect to see a background image when there's a video player on top of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following with `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` alongside `text-align: center`:

```css
div#video1 {
  display: table-cell;/*add display table-cell so you can use vertical-align*/
  background-color: green;
  background-size: 110%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 500px;
  height: 450px;
  vertical-align: middle;/*add vertical align middle to achieve vertical align to the middle*/
  text-align: center;/*use text align center for horizontal align*/
}
div#video2 {
  display: table-cell;/*add display table-cell so you can use vertical-align*/
  background-color: red;
  background-size: 10%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 500px;
  height: 450px;
  vertical-align: middle;/*add vertical align middle to achieve vertical align to the middle*/
  text-align: center;/*use text align center for horizontal align*/
}
.videos {
  margin-top: 40px;
  display: table;/*add display table to main container*/
}
```

```html
<div class="videos">
  <div id="video1">
    <iframe width="450" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vr0dXfQQfNU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <div id="video2">
    <iframe width="450" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fevkx229XBs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```